# I want to pass data between pages ionic 4

Tags: angular, routes, angular7, ionic4

I want to pass data between pages ionic 4 without changing url.

*Code:*

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'detail/:id', loadChildren: './detail/detail.module#DetailPageModule' },
];
```

**home.ts**

```
nextClicked(){
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/detail/' + '11');
  }
```

**detail.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    let output= this.activatedroute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log("data recived is ",JSON.stringify(output))
  }
```

**Output:** data recived is null

Also the URL in browser is changing to http://localhost:8101/contact/11

I want my url to stay like default http://localhost:8101/ is this possible in ionic 4 ?

***please help and thanks in advance!***

Comment: You have to use @input decorator to pass the data

Comment: As i am new to ionic4 if can share the code it wil be helpfull

Comment: It is not related to ionic, it is basic of angular

Comment: https://medium.com/mr-frontend-community/angular-7-share-component-data-with-other-components-1b91d6f0b93f

Comment: You can even use RxJs Subject check this blog http://coding-karma.com/2018/05/06/angular-5-sharing-data-components-using-rxjs-subject/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you route between pages your URL is meant to change. so if you don't wanna change your URL then the only way is hiding and showing the components using flags. However from ionic 4, It is advisable to use Angular routing instead of Ionic Nav controller, this [article](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-angular-routing-with-ionic-4/) can give you the insight about it

You are using NavController API to navigate but extracting the data from angular routing ActivatedRoute API. you should navigate using the Angular Routing API as below

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  navigate(){
   this.router.navigate(['/detail', { id: "123" }]);
  }
}
```

and then you can extract using ActivatedRoute API as below

```
let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

Comment: from where do i pass my 'id' parameter.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect your comment
 this.router.navigate(['/detail', { id: "123" }]);

Answer (score 0):

Pass your variable like this.

```js
constructor(private router: Router){}

sampleFunction(){
   this.router.navigate(['/detail', {id: "11"}]);
}
```

And in the page you want to extract, import all these:

```js
import { NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Route } from '@angular/router';
```

Assume you want to grab that data into a variable called `v1`. Grab it using `ActivatedRoute`:

```js
this.v1 = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
console.log(this.v1);
```

And make sure to import `NavParams` and add these lines into your providers in `app.module.ts` file:

```
providers: [NavParams]
```